# Make only specific path stretchable for vectors

Tags: android, vector

This is the original vector:
[image: original]
This what normally happen if you stretch a vector along x-axis:
[image: stretch1]
This is what I want to achieve:
[image: stretch2]
I know that I can achieve this by making custom view class or creating separate views. But I want to know if there is any way to achieve this using only resource file something similar to 9-patch but for vector.

Comment: So, you want a vector which behaves like a 9 patch...